# Efficient dense diagonal matrix generation in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

Given a complex array `data`, I need to construct a band-diagonal matrix in the form of

[image]

using matlab or python, where * means the complex conjugate. For now I'm using `diag(data(k)*ones(1,n-k),k)` to get the k-th diagonal, then put it in a loop that iterates over k and at the same time do conjugate for negative k, and then taking the sum. However, this is inside another loop and profiling shows that this procedure takes a really long time. The matrix is not sparse and is quite big (~2000x2000). Is there another way to achieve this efficiently? It is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028566/matlab-filling-matrix-diagonalwise), maybe I can define `a` in that question to be `a = [ data(n)^*, data(n-1)^*,  ..., data(0), data(1), ...]` but a cleaner approach is much appreciated. Also, my case is more symmetric than the linked question, so maybe a better solution is possible.

MWE for my code, which took ~170 sec. to run on my pc:

```
tn=2000;
ats=randn(1,tn)+1j*randn(1,tn);

cm=0;
for jx=-tn+1:tn-1
    if jx>=0
        cm=cm+diag(ats(jx+1)*ones(1,tn-abs(jx)),jx);
    else
        cm=cm+diag(conj(ats(-jx+1))*ones(1,tn-abs(jx)),jx);
    end
end
```

Comment: Share your loopy code?

Comment: This might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028566/matlab-filling-matrix-diagonalwise/

Comment: Should be enough to use: `a = [flip(conj(data(2:end))), data]` and then the answer of the other question.

Comment: As you keep adding information to your question: Once you have accepted an answer by clicking on the check mark, you signalize that the problem has been solved. If you are not yet 100% content with the answers, it's ok to wait some time until you think that no better answers will arrive. Maybe skim [this question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so you know when and what to accept.

Comment: @knedlsepp Thanks for the info on proper etiquette on the site. I'm happy with the answer provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the approach given in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028566/matlab-filling-matrix-diagonalwise/):

```
a = [conj(data(end:-1:2)), data];
n = (numel(a)+1)/2;
A = a(bsxfun(@minus, n+1:n+n, (1:n).'));
```

Comment: This is fast indeed! Good job!

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks! It's not easy to have a better `bsxfun`-solution than yours, so I had to post it. ;-)

Comment: Certainly much better use of `bsxfun`! :)

Answer (score 3):

This might solve it -

```
%// Length of input data
N = numel(data)

%// Conjugate of input data
cdata = conj(data) 

%// Circulating indices
idx = mod(bsxfun(@plus,[N:-1:1]',0:N-1),N)+1 %//'

%// Fill upper triangular part with given data and lower triangular with 
%// conjugate data. The first element of data going into the main diagonal.
out = triu(data(idx)) + tril(cdata(idx.'),-1)
```

Sample run -

```
data =
   0.1925 + 0.8901i
   0.8126 + 0.9481i
   0.1138 + 0.3276i
   0.0469 + 0.4714i

out =
   0.1925 + 0.8901i   0.8126 + 0.9481i   0.1138 + 0.3276i   0.0469 + 0.4714i
   0.8126 - 0.9481i   0.1925 + 0.8901i   0.8126 + 0.9481i   0.1138 + 0.3276i
   0.1138 - 0.3276i   0.8126 - 0.9481i   0.1925 + 0.8901i   0.8126 + 0.9481i
   0.0469 - 0.4714i   0.1138 - 0.3276i   0.8126 - 0.9481i   0.1925 + 0.8901i
```

Comment: Great! Cut down the time to 0.483173 seconds from my 170 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: @egwenesedai Awesomeness!!